# Difference in output when using panda.read_csv vs numpy.loadtext

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently doing Andrew Ng's course on ML using Python, I googled to see if my outputs matched others but I realised just because of using numpy instead of panda my final output shifted

Expected : 2105448288.6292474
My output : 2064911681.618526

is this much discrepancy often observed when using different modules?

Reference Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('ex1data2.txt', sep = ',', header = None)
X = data.iloc[:,0:2] # read first two columns into X
y = data.iloc[:,2] # read the third column into y
m = len(y) # no. of training samples
data.head()

X = (X - np.mean(X))/np.std(X)

ones = np.ones((m,1))
X = np.hstack((ones, X))
alpha = 0.01
num_iters = 400
theta = np.zeros((3,1))
y = y[:,np.newaxis]

def computeCostMulti(X, y, theta):
    temp = np.dot(X, theta) - y
    return np.sum(np.power(temp, 2)) / (2*m)
J = computeCostMulti(X, y, theta)

def gradientDescentMulti(X, y, theta, alpha, iterations):
    m = len(y)
    for _ in range(iterations):
        temp = np.dot(X, theta) - y
        temp = np.dot(X.T, temp)
        theta = theta - (alpha/m) * temp
    return theta
theta = gradientDescentMulti(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)

J = computeCostMulti(X, y, theta)
print(J)
```

My Code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data = np.loadtxt("ex1data2.txt", delimiter = ",", dtype = 'int')
x = data[:, 0:2]
y = data[:, 2]
m = len(y)

x = x.reshape(m,2)
y = y.reshape(m,1)
one = np.ones((m,1))

X = np.matrix(x)

X = (X - np.mean(X))/np.std(X)

X = np.concatenate((one,X), axis = 1)

theta = np.zeros((3, 1))

def cc(theta, X, y):
    A = np.dot(X,theta)-y
    return float(((1/(2*m)) * np.dot(A.T, A)))


def gd(theta, X, y, alpha, iterations):
    for i in range(iterations):
        h = np.dot(X, theta)-y
        h = np.dot(X.T, h)
        theta = theta - (alpha/m) * h
    return theta

theta = (gd(theta, X, y, 0.01, 400))

print(cc(theta, X, y))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is due to how matrix operations are applied to a pandas dataframe vs numpy matrix.

e.g., pandas dataframe:

```py
data = pd.read_csv('ex1data2.txt', header=None)
X_df = data.iloc[:, 0:2]
np.mean(X_df)

# 0    2000.680851
# 1       3.170213
# dtype: float64
```

vs numpy matrix:

```py
data = np.loadtxt('ex1data2.txt', delimiter=',', dtype='int')
x = data[:, 0:2]
X_mat = np.matrix(x)
np.mean(X_mat)

# 1001.9255319148937
```

Here `axis=0` is required to replicate the pandas behavior:

```py
np.mean(X_mat, axis=0)

# matrix([[2000.68085106,    3.17021277]])
```

I haven't walked through every line of your numpy version to debug every discrepancy, but this is the underlying cause. The data loaded from `pd.read_csv` and `np.load_txt` are equivalent. It's the subsequent matrix operations that differ due to axis handling.

Comment: however due to the difference of matrix operations the values differ significantly, which in practical life can cause a lot of disruptions, is it always a good practice to specify "axis" when using numpy commands?

Comment: technically, yes i would say it's probably good practice to make the axis explicit. realistically, people usually leave out the axis when it's the default axis, but as you encountered here, default behavior can change based on libraries, data structures, or possibly even versions.